# Whats the "name" of a trust certificate in ldaptive?

Tags: java, ssl, x509, keytool

Reading the Javadocs/grep code for [`X509CredentialConfig`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ldaptive/ldaptive/1.0.2/org/ldaptive/ssl/X509CredentialConfig.java#X509CredentialConfig.0trustCertificates):

```
// Name of the trust certificates to use for the SSL connection.
private String trustCertificates;
```

When I run `keytool -list` on the Java KeyStore that my app is using:

```
keytool -list -keystore myjks.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

<SOME-BIG-KEY-NAME>, May 1, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry
```

Is the `trustCertificates` property the same as my key alias (hence, should I set it to `<SOME-BIG-KEY-NAME>`? Or is there a difference between key alias and the name of the trust certificate?

Comment: When you say "*Whats the “name” of a trust certificate in Java?*", this doesn't seem to have much to do with "Java" in general. Rather, your question seems very specific to the "ldaptive" library.

Comment: LDAP doesn't have anything to do with this, only the ldaptive library.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `trustCertificates` is a list of 1+ URLs, comma-delimited, where each URL is a path to an actual certificate file. In my case, I had to export the cert out of my keystore, and because it was packaged up inside my WAR file, and I was using Spring, I was able to use the `classpath:` qualifier to help Ldaptive find the cert file.

```
trustCertificates = "classpath:/WEB-INF/my-exported-cert.cer";
```